# Display elements in order of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I have elements .show in the order they're clicked and not the order they're appear in the HTML using jquery?

E.g.

Css code:

```
.sq{
    display:none;
}
```

Html Code:

```
<a href="#" id="1">A</a>
<a href="#" id="2">B</a>
<a href="#" id="3">C</a>

<span class="sq" id="01">a</span>
<span class="sq" id="02">b</span>
<span class="sq" id="03">c</span>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$("#1").click(function(){
  $("#01").show();
});

$("#2").click(function(){
  $("#02").show();
});

$("#3").click(function(){
  $("#03").show();
});
```

Using this code if I click C,B,A the output will arrange "a b c"

What I would like is if I click C,B,A the output should arrange "c b a"

I've tried various CSS positioning rules to do this, but the best I can do is have them arrange in the same position as each other. I realize I could make a new class for each but would rather not do it that way in the interest of minimal code and I'm learning right now so it would be useful to know a better way around the issue.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xuxsuagg/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this code to:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var text = document.createTextNode(this.innerHTML + " ");
    span.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].appendChild(span);
  })
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sq {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="1">A</a>
<a href="#" id="2">B</a>
<a href="#" id="3">C</a>
<a href="#" id="4">D</a>
<a href="#" id="5">E</a>
<a href="#" id="6">F</a>

<p class="output">

</p>
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer since it fits my needs perfectly, this is my fault and nobody else's however clicking AAACCCBBB should display this same output too, this code does that even without me having to ask. Which is great, but thank you to everyone else too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple trick: use `.append()`. When you append a selected element that is already present in the DOM, you are actually moving it around. Also, I recommend that to optimize your code, you can:

- Use a common class for the `<a>` elements
- Assigned a HTML5 `data-` attribute, say `data-target`, to specify the ID of its intended target
- Listen to click events triggered on the common class

An example of the proposed new markup:

```
<a href="#" class="sq-click" data-target="01">A</a>
<a href="#" class="sq-click" data-target="02">B</a>
<!-- and more -->
```

Here is the code (and the demo fiddle here—http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/xuxsuagg/9/)

```
$('.sq-click').click(function(e) {
    // Prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Use .append() to move element
    var $out = $('.output');
    $out.find('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).appendTo($out).show();
});
```

---

On a side note, if you do not want the users to rearrange the order after an anchor has been clicked, you will have to rely on the `.one()` method for listening to click events. Also, it will help that you style the disabled anchors appropriately so the users can see it—see proof-of-concept demo: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/xuxsuagg/26/

```
$('.sq-click').one('click', function(e) {
    // Prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Use .append() to move element
    var $out = $('.output');
    $out.find('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).appendTo($out).show();

    // Add class to change appearance of disabled <a>
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

And your CSS can look like this:

```
.disabled {
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```js
$(".myclass").one('click', function() {
  $($(this).data('target')).appendTo('.output').show();
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sq {
  display: none;
}
.output {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="1" class="myclass" data-target="#01">A</a>
<a href="#" id="2" class="myclass" data-target="#02">B</a>
<a href="#" id="3" class="myclass" data-target="#03">C</a>
<a href="#" id="4" class="myclass" data-target="#04">D</a>
<a href="#" id="5" class="myclass" data-target="#05">E</a>
<a href="#" id="6" class="myclass" data-target="#06">F</a>

<p class="output">
  <span class="sq" id="01">A</span>
  <span class="sq" id="02">B</span>
  <span class="sq" id="03">C</span>
  <span class="sq" id="04">D</span>
  <span class="sq" id="05">E</span>
  <span class="sq" id="06">F</span>
</p>
```

Notes

- Used a common event handler instead of using different handlers for each link
- Before shown the element the target is moved to the last position of the parent
- Used .one() to register the handler so that one element is shown only once

Answer (score 0):

Bind the click event to the class that they share and not their own unique id.
In the function scope of clickClosure 'this' is referring to the current element.

```
$(".sq").click(function clickClosure(){
  $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using styles to achieve this might range from painful to very hard, depending on the exact way you want them displayed. I'd suggest instead to re-order them in DOM. That might look something like this:

```
<a id="link-1">...</a>
...
<div style="display: none" id="hidden-items">
    <span id="item-1">...</span>
</div>
<div id="visible-items"></div>
```

&

```
$('#link-1').click(function () {
    $('#visible-items').append($('#item-1'));
});
```

---

As other respondents suggested, you could also optimize your code in various ways, but that's outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can put empty `<p class="output">` and remove `display:none;` from CSS `.sq{..`. In jQuery, create a `<span>` on the basis of clicked link and append it to `<p class="output">`

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="1">A</a>
<a href="#" id="2">B</a>
<a href="#" id="3">C</a>
<a href="#" id="4">D</a>
<a href="#" id="5">E</a>
<a href="#" id="6">F</a>

<p class="output">

</p>
```

CSS:

```
.sq{
/*display:none;*/
color: green;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("a[href='#']").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = '<span class="sq" id="0'+$(this).prop('id')+'">'
             +$(this).text()+'</span>';
  $(text).appendTo('p.output');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xuxsuagg/30/)**